# JavaScript - Running different RegEx engines

Tags: javascript, regex, module, runtime, ecma

I'd like to write JavaScript code that runs regular expression engines other than the one built into it and returns the matches.

My goal is to make a website where people can upload a RegEx, specify the engine and have the result shown to them.

After doing some looking I'm pretty sure that such a library doesn't exist, nor is there anything with any interest in running non-JavaScript RegEx. Nor was there for Ruby.

What exactly would this look like? The part that confuses me (not really sure how to begin) is interfacing with non-JavaScript code designed for other programming languages.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Which regex engine(s) do you want to run? Why do you want to do this? Why can't you just execute some code in a language that runs on that engine?

Comment: All of them, any of them. My goal is to make a website where people can upload a RegEx, test it against a string and have the result shown to them. I  should probably specify that. I've also realised that this question is probably more relevant to JavaScript. Will update answer.

Comment: You would need to run the different languages in back end. Use websockets to communicate between front and back.

Comment: @charlietfl That's a start.

Comment: Could probably use heroku for example to set up several different environments and use one as master

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/ibaaj/Regex101.com-offline-app.

Comment: @JackHasa Do you want to make this available to the public? There are many sites that offer exactly what you describe. Here are some: https://gist.github.com/fghber/44febf440c8dead56da92e50d4e02a03

Comment: @wp78de I do, it's a personal endeavour though.

Comment: @wp78de that's a handy resource!